# How to use two @click $emit function in vue.js with electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm developing login page with connect with SSHFS drive.

And some of the functions are working but, I'm confusing with my codes. I analyze my code but I don't know why it's working, and why this is working.

My application looks like this.

[image]

It's just simple login web app with Electron. So When I click login and if the ID & and password is right, it will mount SSHFS drive and goes to system tray icon to hide. After that it should open the explorer that mounted folder.

So I thought When I click login button, and two @click with $emit functions should work like this.

```
      <div class="form-item">
      <button class="login" v-show="showConnectButton" :class="{ 'success': isConnected, 'connecting-disconnecting': isConnectingOrDisconnecting }" :disabled="isConnectingOrDisconnecting" @click="[$emit(isConnected ? 'disconnect' : 'connect', conn), $emit('open', conn.mountPoint)]">{{isConnected ? 'disconnect' : 'login'}}</button>
      </div>
```

I use this code but it seems the code tries mount the drive early then $emit(isConnected) function so It shows the error that Cannot find 'E' Drive that I set in another code.
[image]

It's an error that 'System cannot find 'E' drive in my computer'

I tried to put mount function to another function but it doesn't work. Only the 'Hide to tray' and 'Mount Drive function' works well. So I think it should fix only a few code and it will work but I don't know where should I fix the code.

And I already searched in stackoverflow questions but it seems doesn't fit in my question.
Here's my part of my full code. Please check the code and give me some advise. Thanks.

**My ConnectionItem.vue full Code**

```
<template>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="form-item">
      <button class="login" v-show="showConnectButton" :class="{ 'success': isConnected, 'connecting-disconnecting': isConnectingOrDisconnecting }" :disabled="isConnectingOrDisconnecting" @click="[$emit(isConnected ? 'disconnect' : 'connect', conn)]">{{isConnected ? 'disconnect' : 'login'}}</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { remote } from 'electron'
import Icon from '@/components/Icon'

const window = remote.getCurrentWindow()

export default {
  name: 'connection-item',

  components: {
    Icon
  },

  props: {
    conn: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },

    mode: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'none'
    }
  },

  computed: {

    isConnected (conn) {
      // this.isActive = !this.enable
      this.$emit('open', conn.mountPoint)
      window.hide()
      return this.conn.status === 'connected'
    },

    isConnectingOrDisconnecting () {
      return this.conn.status === 'connecting' || this.conn.status === 'disconnecting'
    },

    showConnectButton () {
      // window.hide()
      // openLocal(path);
      // this.$emit('open', conn.mountPoint)
      return this.mode === 'none' || this.isConnected || this.isConnectingOrDisconnecting
    },

    isEditing () {
      return this.mode === 'edit' && !this.isConnected && !this.isConnectingOrDisconnecting
    },

    showDeleteButton () {
      return this.mode === 'delete' && !this.isConnected && !this.isConnectingOrDisconnecting
    },

    showRunningInBackgroundNotification () {
      if (!this.runningInBackgroundNotificationShowed) {
        if (this.$store.state.Settings.settings.displayTrayMessageOnClose) {
          this.notify('program runs in background (network connected)') // 1
          this.notify('Click Quit button when you disconnect drive') // 2

          this.runningInBackgroundNotificationShowed = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```